# How do I fix plotting my boxplot?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to plot my boxplot but I am getting a 'nonetype attribute error.'

Please, how can I fix this?

My Code:

```
Failed = train_df['Fees'][train_df['Passedornot'] == 0]
Passed = train_df['Fees'][train_df['Passedornot'] ==1]


average_fees = DataFrame([mean(Passed), mean(Failed)])
std_fees = DataFrame([standard_deviation(Passed), standard_deviation(Failed)])
fig, axis4 = plt.subplots(1,1)
train_df['Fees'].plot(kind='hist', figsize=(15,5),bins=100, xlim=(0,30), ax=axis4)


fig, axis5 = plt.subplots(1,1)
average_fees.plot(kind='', legend=False, ax=axis5)
```

Error:

```
average_fees.plot(kind='bp', legend=False, ax=axis5)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Sample of Data:

```
    Name        Sex     Age Score    Passedornot Fees
    Tim Cole    male    18   148          1       90
    Ellen James female  47   143          1       80
    Jerome Miles male   62   144          0       80
    Waltz Albert male   27   153          0       90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happens there, but I think your `average_fees` is not a proper pandas dataframe. Furthermore, my compiler is complaining about `kind='bp'`. That is one of the reasons why the community always asks for a fully functional working example.

Here is a working snippet for Python3, run in a Jupyter notebook, for the piece of data you provided saved to a file sample.txt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
train_df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', sep='\t')
# train_df.head()
Failed = train_df['Fees'][train_df['Passedornot'] == 0]
Passed = train_df['Fees'][train_df['Passedornot'] == 1]
average_fees = pd.DataFrame([np.mean(Passed), np.mean(Failed)])
std_fees = pd.DataFrame([np.std(Passed), np.std(Failed)])

fig1, axis4 = plt.subplots(1,1)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(train_df.Fees, 100, linewidth=1)
plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 3])
plt.show()

fig2, axis5 = plt.subplots(1,1)
# print(type(average_fees))
average_fees.boxplot(return_type='axes')
```

Comment: Thanks! i was going the creating functions route, but this works much better. I was able to get one boxplot but this does not plot the two as 0 and 1, Failed and Passed with their standard deviations? Any thoughts on how i can modify this to do that?

Comment: Maybe, you could try something like `train_df.boxplot(column='Fees', by='Passedornot', return_type='axes')`? You can select the criterion by which you want to select data using `by`. If you skip the `column=...`, it shows you several plots of all the rows containing numerical data.